# Connect Site to M365 Group Missing

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365

What happened to the option to connect to a new M365 Group? This was part of our provisioning process. Create, the classic team site, make changes to the permission levels, connect the M365 Group, then create the Teams Team.

[image]

Does this have to be done programmatically now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can still connect the Group, but for some reason, the link has been removed when on the Home page. If you navigate to Site Information => View All Site Settings, the link is available:

[image]

It may be a bug as @Callum stated, but at least there's a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a classic team site template, then this should still be possible via the UI: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/transform/modernize-connect-to-office365-group#connect-a-microsoft-365-group-using-the-sharepoint-user-interface

You can raise a bug with Microsoft via the Microsoft 365 admin portal if you are unable to do so.

Answer (score 1):

From your screenshot, the template for your site is "Team site (no Office 365 group)", which is a modern view site without office 365 group by default.

However, "Connect to New Microsoft 365 group" UI option only applies to **classic templates** like the classic team site template **(STS#0)** and community site template **(COMMUNITY#0)**, and your team site template is "STS#3",so the button missed.

Difference between STS#0 and STS#3:

[image]   [image]

To find the site template via viewing the source of the start page (Ctrl + U) and search for JavaScript variable:

```
webTemplateConfiguration
```

As a workaround, we suggest you use powershell to connect the site to a new Microsoft 365 group:

```
$UserName = "user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"   
$SPOAdminCenterUrl = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"   
$ClassicSPOSite = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/ClassicSPOSite/"   
  
$O365Cred = Get-Credential -UserName $UserName  
Connect-SPOService -Url $SPOAdminCenterUrl -Credential $O365Cred   
  
$GroupDisplayName="<Group Display Name>"   
$GroupAlias="<GroupAlias>"   
Set-SPOSiteOffice365Group -Site $ClassicSPOSite -DisplayName $GroupDisplayName -Alias $GroupAlias -IsPublic $true
```

More information:

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/connect-a-classic-experience-sharepoint-team-site-to-a-new-microsoft-365-group-469c6ee0-2139-4496-9914-7e39d07ac49d?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/connect-sharepoint-site-to-office-365-group/

Comment: The question states that he created a classic team site, not a modern site.

Comment: Yes, it's the classic site with modern view.